# Locking a fragment after switching

Tags: android

I have a query about locking of fragments.Actually I have three fragments in bottom tab navigation.
All of the three fragments are basically entry forms in which I am picking the values from edittexts.However I want a feature to be added in the app such that when I submit one form i.e. when one fragment submits the data, then that fragment should be locked from user switching and user cant go back to that old fragment and an alert message should be displayed, displaying the message that you have already submitted this section,now you cant go back.Can anyone suggest how to make it possible.

e.g. I have three fragments frg1,frg2,frg3 and each of them contains a form to get data.Each of them has a submit button located in the below after the form.Once you submit you goto next fragment automatically(this is already done) but you need to take care that you can not go back to the old fragment again.Till now I have coded the part where you can switch to another fragment after submission but I am still able to go back.So basically i need that feature to stop going back to the old fragment.Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using a viewpager the only solution is create a Custom ViewPager like this:

```
public class NoScrollViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean isPagingEnabled = false;

public NoScrollViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public NoScrollViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
    this.isPagingEnabled = b;
}
```

With setPagingEnabled() you will be able to lock and unlock the viewPager

Otherwise if you are inflating fragment use replace() instead add().

Cheers.

Comment: Hi Panabuntu,I am not using viewpager directly.Actually I am using roughhike/bottomtab navigation.Can you suggest some way to incorporate this change into that

Comment: You can use this function and make the tab INVISIBLE or GONE. And the user will not be able to select that tab.
mBottomBar.getTabAtPosition(position).setVisibility(View.GONE);
BTW, you should specify in the topic which third party library are you using :)